# Isotope Packery layout makes an irregular gutter space

Tags: jquery-isotope, packery

**Problem**

- For some viewport width, Isotope makes an irregular gutter between grid items.
- This happens when page reload. After that, when I resize window browser, Isotope has a good behaivor.

**Example when browser reload contents** (wrong gutter space)

[image: Example when page reloads]

**Example after resize viewport** (right zero gutter space)

[image: Example after resize viewport]

[Here is the codepen example](http://codepen.io/aitormendez/pen/YGWoaP?editors=0010#0)

**Javascript**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
       layoutMode: 'packery',
       itemSelector: '.grid-item',
       packery: {
         gutter: 0
       }
     });
 });
```

## UPDATE

I have a codepen working with simplified HTML `.grid-item` and imageloaded(). [Here it is.](http://codepen.io/aitormendez/pen/rrrNYJ)

I have not solution yet, but I'm getting close.

The `.grid-item` looks like this now:

```
<article class="grid-item col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pequena">
    <img width="699" height="466" src="http://stage.lolafonseca.com/app/uploads/2016/08/reforma-3-699x466.jpg" class="img-responsive wp-post-image" alt="reforma-3"/>
  </article>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got it. The problem was solved with `imagesLoaded()` (I was trying it without install imagesLoaded library and, obviously, it didn't work. I didn't know it was a library separated of Isotope). After install the library, all works.

http://codepen.io/aitormendez/pen/YGWoaP

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    layoutMode: 'packery',
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    packery: {
      gutter: 0
    }
  });
  $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.isotope('layout');
});
});
```